# JSON Schema reference resolution

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JSON schema that contains "$ref" tags and I am trying to get a version of the JSON schema that have the "$ref" tags resolved.  I am only looking to resolve "$ref" from definition (tags) within the JSON Schema string (ie. not external resolution needed).

Is there a library that performs the resolution of the JSON Schema?  (I am currently using org.everit.json.schema library, which is great, but I can't find how to do what I need).

For example, my original schema is:

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/arrays.schema.json",
  "description": "A representation of a person, company, organization, or place",
  "title": "complex-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fruits": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "vegetables": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/veggie" }
    }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "veggie": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "veggieName", "veggieLike" ],
      "properties": {
        "veggieName": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name of the vegetable."
        },
        "veggieLike": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "Do I like this vegetable?"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which would resolve to something like this (notice that the "#defs/veggie" resolves to its definition inserted inline in the schema):

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/arrays.schema.json",
  "description": "A representation of a person, company, organization, or place",
  "title": "complex-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fruits": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "vegetables": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [ "veggieName", "veggieLike" ],
        "properties": {
          "veggieName": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The name of the vegetable."
          },
          "veggieLike": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "description": "Do I like this vegetable?"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible in the general sense, because:

- the $ref might be recursive (i.e. reference itself again)
- the keywords in the $ref might duplicate some of the keywords in the containing schema, which would cause some logic to be overwritten.

Why do you need to alter the schema in this way? Generally, a JSON Schema implementation will resolve the $refs automatically while evaluating the schema against provided data.

Comment: Recursion errors may be present but they would/should be captured in any validation effort.  As to why I need it: my application requires the fully resolved JSON schema as it is used to process downstream requests for my application (but that is probably irrelevant to my original request).  I can probably do some simple JSON parsing (and replace $ref tag with definitions), but as you highlight there could be complications which is why i am looking for a library that does this...

Comment: "to process downstream requests for your application"? are you not using a JSON Schema evaluator for this? It will resolve $refs for you dynamically at runtime. Recursion isn't an error, it's a feature :)

Comment: My downstream application needs a JSON schema which gets transformed into another format, but unfortunately the downstream app cannot process JSON schemas with $refs (and it is old and not under my control and I cannot change it) so I need the $ref resolved... either way, the solution should be able accept recursion and determine if it is valid or not...